# Diamond operator in raw type context

Tags: java, generics

I saw code like this today:

```
public class GenClass<T> { ... }

//in some other class
GenClass g = new GenClass<>();
```

Does the `<>` accomplish anything at all here?  Normally `<>` would tell the compiler to determine the generic parameter(s) based on context, but in this case there's no context.  But apparently it's legal.  Is there any difference between this and the following?

```
GenClass g = new GenClass();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diamond is doing what it always does - inferring the generic type from the context, and providing assurance that the constructor call does not compromise type-safety.

Consider this example:

```
public class GenClass<T> {

    GenClass(T t, List<T> list) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenClass m = new GenClass<>(1, new ArrayList<String>());  // Doesn't compile
    }
}
```

This example does not compile, because an appropriate type could not be inferred. If you remove the diamond it does compile because the types of the constructor arguments are the erased versions (`Object` and `List`).

In your case, the constructor takes no arguments, so there is nothing really to check. However, using a diamond is a good habit to get into, even when you choose to assign the result of a constructor invocation to `Object` or a raw type (not that you should use raw types).

Comment: Would `GenClass g = new GenClass<>();` be the same as `GenClass g = new GenClass<Object>();` ?

Comment: @flkes Yes it would. If `g` is a raw type it makes no difference what type you put on the right.

Answer (score -2):

I am just copy/pasting it from [this blog](http://tronicek.blogspot.ca/2011/03/do-we-really-need-in-diamond-operator.html). Its not mine, just found it relevant to the answer.

**Actual Post By Zdeněk Troníček**

As you may know, one of new features of upcoming Java 7 will be the diamond operator. Purpose of the diamond operator is to simplify instantiation of generic classes. For example, instead of

```
List<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

with the diamond operator we can write only

```
List<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>();
```

and let compiler infer the value of type argument. Nice simplification. But do we really need to write `<>`? Isn't `new ArrayList()` enough? In this article, I will describe the arguments of the `<>` proponents and explain why I think that these arguments are not very strong. However, I also describe arguments why we need `<>`.

In Java 1.4, we had raw types only:

```
List p = new ArrayList();
```

Java 5 introduced generics:

```
List<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Many types in Java API were generified and even though we can still use generic types as raw types, there is no reason for this in Java 5 or newer. When generics were introduced, raw types were allowed for backward compatibility so that we could gradually and smoothly adopt generics. For example, code in Java 1.4 can be combined with new generic code because raw and generic types are allowed together. This is also expressed in the JLS (4.8 Raw Types):

*"The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types."*

Now let's go back to the diamond operator and ask again: "Do we really need <>?". The proponents of the <> syntax say that we need <> to preserve backward compatibility. Let's look at an [example](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2011-February/003082.html) from the coin-dev conference:

```
class Foo<X> {
   Foo(X x) { }
   Foo<X> get(X x) { return this; }
}

class Test {
   void test() {
      Foo<?> f1 = new Foo(1).get(""); //ok - can pass String where Object is expected
      Foo<?> f2 = new Foo<>(1).get(""); //fail - cannot pass String where Integer is expected
   }
}
```

This shows the difference between new Foo(1) and new Foo<>(1). Clearly, these two are different and if we changed the semantics of new Foo(1), it would break backward compatibility. But wait. Backward compatibility with what? Isn't line

```
Foo<?> f1 = new Foo(1).get("");
```

a little suspicious? It uses generic type in the left part and raw type in the right part. Although it is legal, it is probably either omission or malpractice. And its legality is probably only a side effect of "a concession to compatibility of legacy code".

Let's go further and look at another [example](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2011-February/003089.html) from the coin-dev conference. It shows the difference between raw type and parameterized type with the diamond:

```
public class X<T> {
   public X(T t) { }
   public T get() { return null; }

   public static int f(String s) { return 1; }
   public static int f(Object o) { return 2; }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(f(new X<>("").get()));
      System.out.println(f(new X("").get()));
   }
}
```

Let's play with the code a bit. Let's assume that there was a library with the X class:

```
public class X {
   public X(Object o) { }
   public Object get() { return null; }
}
```

and some code that compiled against this library:

```
public class Client {
   static int f(String s) { return 1; }
   static int f(Object o) { return 2; }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(f(new X("").get()));
   }
}
```

Then, the library was generified:

```
public class X<T> {
   public X(T t) { }
   public T get() { return null; }
}
```

and we compiled the client project against the generified version. Now, if we changed the semantics of `new X("")` to new `X<String>("")` (or `new X<>("")` with the diamond syntax), the code would behave differently. So, the answer to the title question is 'yes'. If we want to stay backward compatible, we need `<>` and we cannot put `new X("")` semantically equal to new `X<>("")`.

Other questions are how long can Java evolve and remain compatible with concessions to compatibility and whether newcomers to Java will appreciate this.

Comment: Links rot over time. Please explain the relevant part of your article here. This may be deleted otherwise.

Comment: This answer is link only. Please explain the relevant details *in* your answer.

Comment: "I am just copy/pasting it from this blog. Its not mine, just found it relevant to the answer." This is still plagiarism imo.

Comment: How is it plagiarism when i am posting the original link, author name and saying that i just copied from there. Plagiarism would have been if i had claimed that all this explanation belongs to me.

Comment: It's only plagiarism if it is represented as being the original thoughts/work of someone other than the original author. This is clearly credited to the author and therefore not plagiarism.

Comment: It is actually copyright infringement. This is used without the original author's permission.

Comment: While this gives interesting information, I think it doesn't directly address the OP's question and I suspect from the wording of the question that the OP probably already knows what is written in this post. (btw even though it's a copy of copyrighted material, it's a snippet which may come under "fair use")

Comment: You're right in saying that it isn't plagiarism, since you're not claiming these are your own ideas. However, it may be copyright infringement. You should *summarize* and *paraphrase* the points and still cite your source.