# Use of <> in Java generics

Tags: java, generics, diamond-operator

Why is it that Java accept below line of code, with <> only being present on the right?
The <> signs have no (generics functionality) purpose like this?

```
List balloons = new ArrayList<>();
```

So far I only understand the use of <> on the right as shown in below example.
Here Java infers the type  on the left, so there's no need to specify  again on the right and simply <> can be used.

```
    List<String> balloons = new ArrayList<>();
    balloons.add("blue");
    balloons.add("yellow");
    // balloons.add(1); // will not compile as balloons is type safe, demanding String input
    System.out.println(balloons.get(0));
    System.out.println(balloons.get(1));
    // System.out.println(balloons.get(2));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diamond operator in raw type context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363062/diamond-operator-in-raw-type-context)

Comment: Just as a general note, in case it wasnt clear: Never leave out the `<...>` on a generic type, just writing `List balloons` gives you a raw-type. Thats basically a fallback mode for pre Java 5 and is even worse than `List<Object>`, you lose all type safety.

Answer (score 2):

List defined as

```
List balloons = new ArrayList<>();
```

is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), which means you can store anything in this list.

This

```
List balloons = new ArrayList<>();
```

is similar to

```
List<Object> balloons = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

**Note:** Its important to note that `List` and `List<Object>` are *similar* BUT there are differences between them. See: [Java difference between List and List<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885920/java-difference-between-list-and-listobject)

Comment: As a note, `List` and `List<Object>` are similar but different. They behave differently. For example you can do `balloons = dogs;` with raw types on the variable. RIP type safety.

Comment: @Zabuzard Thank you for pointing that out. Added a link in the question that explains the difference between both types.